# Replace image src path using span

Tags: html, jquery, django

Is there any way how to replace the path location using span or etc. that comes from the Jquery, or is there any shorcut in Django?, Currently as you can see I'm trying to override the path that comes from my jquery `src="/media/<span id=image></span>"`. Is there any other way to pass the path image that comes from jquery into the img src?.  It would be great if anybody could figure out where I am doing something wrong. thank you so much in advance

*Jquery*

```
 $(document).on('click', 'a[data-role=show_scanned]', function(){
      let csrf = $('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val();
      var path = $(this).attr('id');  #Image path example:  image.jpg
      var assign = $("#image").html(path);
      $("#scanned_show").modal('show');
 });
```

*html* retrieve

```
<img class="card-img img-fluid mb-1" src="/media/<span id=image></span>" alt="Card image cap" style="width: 900px;height: 600px;">
```

Comment: Why is there HTML in the `src` attribute in the first place? That's the issue you should address, not coming up with a band-aid JS solution. In addition the JS in the question seems to have nothing to do with the `img` element you've shown, so it's not clear what the actual goal here is.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Thanks for your response but , I just want to replace the `img src path` . for example the value that I've been passing is `image.jpg` then I want to pass it dynamically into my `img src ="dynamic_value" `. Is there any other way to pass the path image that comes from jquery into the img src?

Comment: Do you want to put the src attribute as a dynamic string depending on users request from the server?

Comment: @MarieLoise the `id` of the clicked element is a filename which you want to append to the src...? That's even more odd

Comment: @Abdul Aziz Barkat Yes , depends on what the path value that comes from jquery

Comment: @Rory McCrossan Yes, it's somehow value like  `image.jpg`, then I want to pass it to my `img src = `

Comment: In django templates if you are passing a variable in the context you can do something like `<img src="{{ url_path }}">` Where url_path is the variable you are passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line below can get the text of a `span`

```
$("#image").text()
```

You can then assign this to the `src` attribute of the `img` tag:

```
$("#imageDisplay").attr("src", $("#image").text() );
```

Demo:

```js
// Add click event
$("#load").click(function() {

  // Add text from span to src attribute of img
  $("#imageDisplay").attr("src", $("#image").text());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id=image>https://via.placeholder.com/150</span>
<button id="load">Load Image</button>
<img id="imageDisplay">
```

Comment: Thanks it help me a lot :)

Comment: No worries, glad it helped.